# position div on top of canvas AND always in lower right corner of full screen browser

Tags: html, css, position, fullscreen

Given this extremely simple mark-up, how do I position a div, so that it is ALWAYS located on top of the full browser canvas BUT in the lower right of the browser window when the browser is full screen. I only need to target Chrome on Windows.

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="webgl-canvas"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. It works in all browsers, even really old ones

```
#yourSelector {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; right:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[**Demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zE8Q4/)